# Problems related to mutexes in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to understand the concept of multithread programming. I know the concept of deadlock and mutexes but i cannot find an answer to the following question. How the problem of deadlock can arise when mutexes are used?

Comment: Sorry but SO is not your research assistant.  Please edit your post to show the research that you have done.  What code have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia entry on deadlocks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a concrete example of how to provoke [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) in Java. We spawn two threads. The first one acquires a mutex lock on `a`, then waits a second, then tries to acquire a lock on `b`. The second acquires a lock on `b`, then waits, then tries to acquire `a`. The result is that the program enters deadlock and runs forever.

```
public class Deadlock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Object a = new Object();
        final Object b = new Object();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (a) {
                    /* wait for a second to make it likely the other thread can acquire b */
                    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {  }
                    synchronized (b) {
                        System.out.println("Acquired a, then b.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (b) {
                    /* wait for a second to make it likely the other thread can acquire a */
                    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {  }
                    synchronized (a) {
                        System.out.println("Acquired b, then a.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Note that this code is not *guaranteed* to enter deadlock. The thread scheduler is perfectly within its rights to run the first thread to completion before starting on the second thread, **or vice versa**. Due to the massive waiting time in this example, it's pretty much certain the system will enter deadlock, but if instead of sleeping for one second, both threads were doing some computation of a variable time length before each lock acquisition, any of the following things could happen at random:

- deadlock
- `"Acquired a, then b."`, followed by `"Acquired b, then a."`
- `"Acquired b, then a."`, followed by `"Acquired a, then b."`

How do you prevent this from happening?

- Avoid using threads altogether whenever you can get away with it.
- Instead of having shared resources between threads, have each thread operate on its own data, and send each other immutable messages.
- If you absolutely must use shared resources, minimize the number of mutex locks used. If everything synchronizes on the same object, there is only one mutex lock, and deadlock can't happen.
- If you absolutely must have lots of mutex locks, with threads acquiring combinations of them, do the following: write a function that defines a total ordering of the locks. Then, whenever you need to do an operation involving multiple mutexes, create the list of mutexes involved, sort them, then enter them in the sorted order right at the start of the operation.

Have a look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. It contains lots of goodies that take care of many of the truly hairy bits.

Also, I cannot overstate the degree to which the threads may switch in unexpected places. A common mistake is to look at each thread line-by-line and imagine different ways in which the lines could interleave. But that's not enough: a thread might be switched out in the middle of some nested function call deep within some library.

Answer (score 0):

Dead lock is a situation when one thread is locking resource A and waiting for resource B locked by second thread. At the same time second thread is waiting for resource A that is locked by first thread that is waiting for resource B locked by second thread that is.... :)

The solution is to avoid this situation by either "smart" design of threading model or by decoupling of threads using queues or by using immutable objects so that synchronization is not needed etc.

Comment: It is so interesting what were the reasons of down-voter...

Comment: I have no idea, so here's a compensatory upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) object when multiple locks have to obtained in order to avoid lock ordering deadlock. In this case, the method tryLock() in the Lock object will return immediately with the value false. The result is that only a single thread will be holding both locks at the same time. In case of synchronized code the thread will block holding the lock to one object while waiting for the next lock. See the example code below :

```
while (true) {
    if (a.lock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            if (b.lock.tryLock()) {
                try {
                    // manipulate protected state
                } finally {
                    b.lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            a.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Mutex are the key for your synchronized block. Improper usage of synchronized block/mutex variable  leads to dead lock.

Comment: Like to know the reason for downvote :)